# ss command: difference between raw and unix sockets

Tags: command-line, unix-sockets, ss

The `ss` command (from the `iproute2` set of tools which comes as a newer alternative to `netstat`) has in its `--help` the following options

```
   -0, --packet        display PACKET sockets
   -t, --tcp           display only TCP sockets
   -S, --sctp          display only SCTP sockets
   -u, --udp           display only UDP sockets
   -d, --dccp          display only DCCP sockets
   -w, --raw           display only RAW sockets
   -x, --unix          display only Unix domain sockets
```

What exactly is the distinction made here between `RAW` and `UNIX` domain sockets?

And what actually are the `PACKET` sockets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **raw socket** is a [*network* socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) (`AF_INET` or `AF_INET6` usually). It can be used to create raw IP packages which can be used for troubleshooting or to implement your own TCP implementation without using `SOCK_STREAM`:

> Raw sockets allow new IPv4 protocols to be implemented in user space.  A raw socket receives or sends the raw datagram not including link level headers. [[`raw(7)`](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?q=raw&sektion=7&apropos=0&manpath=Debian%208.1.0)]

Tools like `nmap` use raw sockets in order to stop the TCP handshake after the initial `SYN`, `SYN-ACK`, as the TCP connection never completely established. As a network socket, it uses `sockaddr_in` for addresses.

However, the creation of raw sockets is usually restricted. Only privileged processes can create them.

---

A **unix socket** on the other hand is **not** a network socket (`AF_UNIX`). It's a *local* socket:

> The  `AF_UNIX`  (also known as `AF_LOCAL`) socket family is used to communicate between processes on the same machine efficiently. [[`unix(7)`](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?q=unix&sektion=7&apropos=0&manpath=Debian%208.1.0)]

It uses another address structure (`sockaddr_un`). It's a [common way to implement two-way communication on a single system for inter-process communication](https://beej.us/guide/bgipc/html/multi/unixsock.html) without going through the network layer.

---

And **packet sockets** are raw packets at the *driver* level:

> Packet  sockets  are  used to receive or send raw packets at the device driver (OSI Layer 2) level.  They allow the user to implement protocol modules in user space on top of the physical layer. [[`packet(7)`](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?q=packet&apropos=0&sektion=7&manpath=Debian%208.1.0&arch=default&format=html)]

The other sockets act on the *network* layer (OSI Layer 3) or higher. At that point, you're talking directly to your network interface's driver.

For more information see [`socket(2)`](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?q=socket&apropos=0&sektion=2&manpath=Debian%208.1.0&arch=default&format=html), [`ip(7)`](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?q=ip&sektion=7&apropos=0&manpath=Debian%208.1.0), [`packet(7)`](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?q=packet&apropos=0&sektion=7&manpath=Debian%208.1.0&arch=default&format=html), [`raw(7)`](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?q=raw&sektion=7&apropos=0&manpath=Debian%208.1.0), [`socket(7)`](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?q=socket&apropos=0&sektion=7&manpath=Debian%208.1.0&arch=default&format=html) and [`unix(7)`](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?q=unix&sektion=7&apropos=0&manpath=Debian%208.1.0).